# How to import module PyImgur Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm new in python, I've it installed in C:\ & I just started with GAE's Hello World app, I downloaded [PyImgur](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur)  have it installed via cmd `python setup.py install` but I get a error as `ImportError: No module named pyimgur` in the gae logs. So how do I import it in my main.py script?

## app.yaml

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

## main.py

```
import webapp2
import pyimgur

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

## THIS IS THE GAE ERROR

INFO     2013-07-08 08:15:47,197 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:22,289 api_server.py:509] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:22,289 api_server.py:512] Saving search indexes
2013-07-08 08:28:22 (Process exited with code 0)

2013-07-08 08:28:23 Running command: "['C:\Python27\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\fb-app\engineapp']"
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:29,868 devappserver2.py:528] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:29,982 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: `http://localhost:59917`
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:29,989 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: `http://localhost:8080`
INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:29,993 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: `http://localhost:8000`

```
ERROR    2013-07-08 15:28:33,897 wsgi.py:219] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler

    handler = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\fb-app\engineapp\main.py", line 18, in <module>

    import pyimgur

ImportError: No module named pyimgur

INFO     2013-07-08 08:28:33,907 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: **UPADTE** 
A new version v0.4.2 was released & this fixed the issue, of pyimgur import, after the updates I was able to import the module pyimgur in my gae app as well as in python cmd. (thanks for all your input I did include the module files in my app directory as well, it fixed it!)

Answer (score 1):

For modules on the Google App Engine servers, other than those in [official third party libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) you have to upload them with your application code.

For local `dev_appserver`, they have to reside in your `PYTHONPATH`.

The safe way to resolve both is to place the desired module in your application directory, as the `dev_appserver` extends `PYTHONPATH` by it.

Comment: I've set the `PYTHONPATH` in my sys variables path file as `C:\Python27\python.exe`, I can get to python via cmd. so python is ok, now as suggested I did copied the directory named pyimgur in c:\python\ folder from where I did run the setup cmd, after it as suggested I copied the same directory in my app folder c:\app-test\ folder but I still get error. :(

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` has nothing to do with whether you can reach python.exe via `cmd`. That's `PATH` (to the best of my knowledge, I'm not using Windows for development). `PYTHONPATH` is a list of directories that Python looks at for modules you attempt to import. Could you post what your current `PYTHONPATH` is?

Comment: its C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages there I have a folder named as `pyimgur-0.3.2-py2.7.egg`

Comment: Regardless of local installations and .egg files, you should have the pyimgur directory in the application directory. If you do not, when you deploy to GAE, you'll run into the same problem. Create a directory in the same directory as app.yaml, call it "pyimgur" and have its contents the same as [here](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/tree/master/pyimgur). Now, if properly running dev_appserver for your application does not work, I am unable to help you. (You either have misconfigured or conflicting configurations for Python/GAE or I'm unaware of Windows-specific issues with GAE PYTHONPATH)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the pyImgur source code in your app. Include the module in your app directory (the directory where your app.yaml lives), or one of its subdirectory.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I do that? I have extracted the src from zip file then I run the cmd as python `setup.py install` within the directory After that I did copied the directory named **pyimgur-0.3.2** in my app directory as well which has some file & subfolders along setup.py file & then restarted the app BHut still I get the error.. Do I have to state the source for pyImgur in my app.yaml file or main.py file for it to IMPORT the MODULE. HOW? can you pls give an example to include it from a src.

Comment: I would expect simply copying the ["pyimgur" directory](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/tree/master/pyimgur) into the same directory as your app.yaml would work. It's a simple Python module.

Comment: I even tried that as well I also copied the contents/files within that specific folder to my app directory where my app.yaml is But I still get the error.. that's why I'm confused?