# Import error: no module named pyimgur in python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am getting an import error in python when importing pyimgur. I have tried pip install pyimgur but still get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import module PyImgur Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529715/how-to-import-module-pyimgur-python)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it has a other name? look in the map site-packages. there you can find all your site packages. maybe like i say it can have a other name.

Answer (score 0):

pyimgur supports for python 2.x, adding Python 3 to setup.py specifiers and also in pypi metadata. Else try to install with commands "pip3 install pyimgur"